# Mathematics of Magic Squares

Tags: combinatorics, soft-question, self-learning

I have seen many popular accounts of simple magic squares but I would like to find a proper mathematical background to understanding magic squares.  What background knowledge do I need. I am a retired senior school maths teacher.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Hope you stay and contribute to the site :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a 150 year old book by Symes on Magic Squares.  Modern books will take a more abstract approach which may get in the way of learning the classical subject of magic squares.  I'm assuming you don't want to get side-tracked with excessive linear algebra.